# ein dass-Satz als Subjektsatz des eines Satzes, der Subjektsatz eines anderen Satzes ist

Tags: sentence-structure

Ich frage mich, ob der folgende Satz richtig geschrieben ist oder nicht:

> Dass die Zukunft für einen, der ein Diplom in Physik hat, in Italien
>   fraglich ist, ist schon eine Realität, ist offensichtlich

Ich denke schon, aber ich lerne noch Deutsch und deshalb bin ich nicht überzeugt davon. Außerdem habe ich an eine Variante auch gedacht, falls er falsch ist, nämlich:

> Dass die Zukunft für einen, der ein Diplom in Physik hat, in Italien
>   fraglich ist, ist schon eine offensichtliche Realität

Ich hoffe, dass zumindest dieser richtig ist.

Comment: Willst du sagen: _Es ist offensichtlich, dass es schon Realität ist, dass …_ oder: _Es ist offensichtlich schon Realität, dass [Diplomphysiker in Italien fragliche Zukunftsaussichten haben]_?

Comment: Ich will so sagen wie du in erstem Satz geschrieben hast

Comment: Es ist offensichtlich, dass es Sinn ergibt, einen Satz, insbesondere in einer Fremdsprache, möglichst einfach zu halten, weil ein solcher Satz generell, also auch von Muttersprachler, schwer zu verstehen ist, insbesondere wenn durch den erhöhten Schweregrad sich eventuelle Fehler einschleichen, die man nicht erkennt, weil ja der Satz eben schon so komplex ist.

Comment: Auch wenn dein Satz natürlich noch sehr kurz und übersichtlich ist, was ich nur sagen will ist: Versuch es einfach zu halten. Und sobald du dir unsicher bist, ist das ein Anzeichen dafür, dass der Satz schon zu komplex ist. Wobei mir nicht aufgefallen wäre, dass Deutsch nicht deine Muttersprache ist, wenn du nicht "ich lerne noch Deutsch" geschrieben hättest.

Comment: Ein Punkt wirkt da dann Wunder. "Es ist offensichtlich, dass die Zukunft für jemanden, der ein Diplom in Physik hat, in Italien fraglich ist. De facto ist das Realität."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Dass die Zukunft für einen, der ein Diplom in Physik hat, in Italien fraglich ist, ist schon eine Realität, ist offensichtlich.

Hier beziehen sich die beide Sätze auf den ersten Nebensatz („Dass …“), aber so kann man es nicht schreiben, weil der zweite Satz keinen Subjekt hat (der Nebensatz ist das Subjekt vom ersten Satz mit „ich …“). Man würde sie eher mit *und* verbinden:

> […], ist schon eine Realität und ist offensichtlich.

Den zweiten Satz finde ich richtig. Hier sind noch ein paar Umformungen:

> Dass die Zukunft für einen, der ein Diplom in Physik hat, in Italien fraglich ist, ist schon eine Realität, die offensichtlich ist.
>
> Die Realität, dass die Zukunft für einen, der ein Diplom in Physik hat, in Italien fraglich ist, ist offensichtlich.

Answer (score 2):

Ich kann mir keinen Weg denken, die ursprüngliche Konstellation (zweifach verschachtelter Subjektsatz) verständlich zu formulieren. Nach den Regeln der Syntax müßte ein solcher satz mit "Dass dass..." beginnen, was kein Mensch verstehen würde.

Eine alternative Syntax für komplizierte Subjektsätzen bietet das expletive "es": "Es ist offensichtlich, dass...", das aber ebenfalls nicht verschachtelt werden kann.

Am nächsten kommt der vorgeschlagenen Formulierung vielleicht die folgende:

> Dass die Zukunft für einen, der ein Diplom in Physik hat, in Italien fraglich ist, ist schon eine Realität, das ist offensichtlich.

Comment: "Es ist offensichtlich, dass es schon eine Realität ist, dass die Zukunft [...] fraglich ist."